# How to get url of action page after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, url, submit

I have two pages lets say Page A and Page B. Page A send data on form submit to Page B as action i-e form action ="Page B". Page B does some processing and after authentication redirect user to page C if login successful or itself if login fails.

I would like to get url after processing of page B to check that whether it is in page B or redirect to Page C. Below is code for page A.

```
    function can_user_login($username , $password){
    echo '
        <form id = "autoSubmit" action = "Page B" method = "post" target="_blank">
            <input type = "hidden" name= "LoginForm[username]" id = "LoginForm_username" placeholder = "Enter Username" value = "'.$username.'" >
            <input type = "hidden" name= "LoginForm[password]" id = "LoginForm_password" placeholder = "Enter password" value= "'.$password.'" >
            <noscript><input type="submit" value="Click here if you are not redirected."/></noscript>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("autoSubmit").submit();
            </script> 
        </form>


    ';
     //check that after submit it is at page B or redirect to Page C
}
```

Hope that you can understand my question and could help me get to a sollution.
Thanks

Comment: use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: it give the url of current page i-e page A . it want to get url of page B in page A (the one from which form submited)

Comment: then it is correct  because form submitted from A and goes to B  according to your code

Comment: yes form goes from Page A to Page B but in a new tab and page B authenticate user if login fail it redirect to page B (it self) else it is redirect to other page. i want to check that if page B is redirected or not. in page B

Comment: check  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']    with current page url and if same means redirected from b to b (but case is page need to be refreshed)